# Is it possible for the surface area of two shapes be equivilent?

Tags: calculus, area

If squaring the circle is impossible, and this is a well known fact. Can utilizing a cube and a sphere have the same área or i can also consider surface área be the same. Also how would one calcualate this? utiling integrals im guessing.

Comment: Squaring the circle isn't impossible with modern tools. It's only impossible if you restrict yourself to a straitedge and compass.

Comment: Squaring a circle is impossible. However, this only means that you can't do it with a compass and straightedge. You can create a circle with the same area as a square, using an approximation on pi. Likewise, there's no problem constructing a cube and sphere with the same surface area.

Comment: As your question is currently written, I have hard time understanding what you are asking for. What do you mean by "utilizing a cube and sphere"?

Answer (score 2):

"Squaring the circle is impossible" is a theorem of [straightedge-and-compass constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass-and-straightedge_construction) in [plane Euclidean geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry), not an assertion that "a disk and a square cannot have the same area" or anything of that type.

A disk of radius $1/\sqrt{\pi} \approx 0.564189584$ has unit area, as does a square of "radius" $1/2 = 0.5$, i.e., of side length $1$.

Similarly, a sphere of radius $r = \sqrt{3/(2\pi)} \approx 0.690988299$ has the same surface area (namely, $4\pi r^{2} = 6$) as a cube of "radius" $1/2$. This number also cannot be constructed using a straightedge and compass, if that's what you're asking.